# Intersection of planes with 3d vectors

Tags: algebra-precalculus, vectors

The intersection of the planes defined by
${v} \bullet \begin{pmatrix} 8 \\ 1 \\ -12 \end{pmatrix} = 35$
and
${v} \bullet \begin{pmatrix} 6 \\ 7 \\ -9 \end{pmatrix} = 70$
is a line. Find an equation of this line.

I'm not sure how to get from $\mathbf{v} \bullet \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ -1 \\ -3 \end{pmatrix}=0$ to an equation. Any help would be appreciated :) Thank you!

Comment: Um, $v\cdot(2,-1,-3)=0$ is _already_ an equation (though not an equation for anything that looks relevant to the question).

Comment: You can't define a line in space by one equation, unless it is a vector equation. And if the latter is allowed, then how about simply $$\begin{pmatrix}8&1&-12\\6&7&-9\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}35\\70\end{pmatrix}$$ You can do Gaussian elimination on this to find a parametric representation of the line, if you want.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\vec{n_1}=\langle8,1,-12\rangle$ and $\vec{n_2}=\langle6,7,-9\rangle$ are normal vectors for the planes,

the vector $\vec{a}=\vec{n_1}\times\vec{n_2}=\langle75,0,50\rangle$ or, equivalently, $\frac{1}{25}\vec{a}=\langle3,0,2\rangle$ is parallel to the line.

To find a point on the line, setting $z=0$ gives $8x+y=35$ and $6x+7y=70$;

so solving gives $y=7$ and $x=\frac{7}{2}$ and therefore $(\frac{7}{2},7,0)$ is a point on the line.

Therefore the line of intersection has parametric equations $x=\frac{7}{2}+3t,\;\; y=7,\;\; z=2t$.